# Open, closed or connected subsets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Given that $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ is a metric space, consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$:

(a) $\{(-1)^n(\frac{n + 1}{n})\}$

(b) $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [n, \frac{n^2 + 1}{n}]$

(c) $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{1}{2^{n}}]$

(d) $\mathbb{Q}$

(e) $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$

For each subset above, determine if they are open, closed, or not open and not closed, connected or not connected. Then, give the set of accumulation points for each of them. Don't forget to **justify** your answers.

My attempt:

(a) Closed. Not connected.

(b) Unsure.

(c) Unsure.

(d) Neither open nor closed. Not connected.

(e) Neither open nor closed. Not connected.

I am preparing for an exam and this problem was part of a practice set but there are no solutions available. Any assistance with a solution, preferably with an explanation, is much appreciated.

Edit: $\mathbb{N}$ in this case, does not include $0$.

Comment: Are you sure (a) isn't connected? Have you drawn a picture of that set on the number line? As for (b) and (c), start by simplifying the set itself (perhaps it's just an interval), then answer the given question. In (b), should the left endpoint be $\frac1n$ instead of $n$?

Comment: @Kraftsman: (a) is clearly not closed: $1$ and $-1$ are limit points that are not in the set. Also, does your $\Bbb N$ include $0$? If not, as appears to be the case, (b) is simply $[1,2]$, and (c) is $\left(0,\frac12\right]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I didn't notice that. According to RobertTheTutor 's answer, it is closed. For me, $\mathbb{N}$ does NOT include $0$.

Comment: @Kraftsman: It is not closed; that answer is wrong. The set is $$\left\{-2,\frac32,-\frac43,\frac54,\ldots\right\}\,.$$ The negative elements are a sequence converging up to $-1$, and the positive ones are a sequence converging down to $1$.

Comment: @GregMartin My bad again. For (b), the right endpoint was wrong. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hmmm alright. Is there a way to formally put this down?

Comment: @Kraftsman: In that case you have $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left[n,n+\frac1n\right]$, which is in closed but not connected. Showing that it’s not connected is easy; you may have to think just a bit to see why it’s closed.

Comment: @Kraftsman: Let $\epsilon>0$. There are $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1m,\frac1n<\epsilon$, $m$ is odd, and $n$ is even. Clearly $$\left|(-1)^m\frac{m+1}m-(-1)\right|=\left|-1-\frac1m+1\right|=\frac1m<\epsilon$$ and $$\left|(-1)^n\frac{n+1}n-1\right|=\frac1n<\epsilon\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

(a) $n$ usually denotes an integer.  If so, you have a totally disconnected set.  EDIT: Wrong here: "You are right that it is closed.  It has one accumulation point, can you see it?"  There are actually two accumulation points, and they are not in the set, therefore it is not closed.  Thanks to those who pointed that out.

To help see this, list the first several terms: $-2/1, 3/2, -4/3, 5/4, -6/5, 7/6, -8/7, 9/8, ...$. The odd terms are all negative: $-2, -4/3, -6/5, -8/7, -10/9...$ and approach $-1$.  Meanwhile the even terms are all positive: $3/2, 5/4, 7/6, 9/8...$ and approach $1$.

(b) actually makes no sense, as all the sets are empty except the first, which is $[1,2]$.  If that is what it actually says, then work with the interval $[1,2]$.  EDIT: Now that the intervals are defined more clearly, $[n, n+ 1/n]$ is a set of disjoint intervals, closed but not connected.

For a closed interval, every point in it is an accumulation point, and the same is true for this union of closed intervals.

(c) This one is $[1/4, 1/2] \cup [1/8, 1/4] \cup ... $. Sketch this out if you need to to see whether it is connected.  The union forms the interval (0, 1/2]. So every point in the set, and 0 as well, are accumulation points.

(d) and (e) you have correct.  Remember the definition of the reals when looking for accumulation points.

Comment: For (b), I did make a minor error. The end interval was supposed to be $\frac{n^2 + 1}{n}$

Comment: And (a) is not closed.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to figure out the accumulation points for (a), (b) and (c). Could you please help with those?

Comment: Added details to my answer.